# How to work Load Balancing in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Basically, I have two questions:

1. To use "Load Balancer" do I need to have two or more instances?
2. Do I need to have my application replicated in each instance?

   For example, I have an application Moodle. My site Moodle is hosted at an instance with a 30Gb volume. And I have an EBS volume of 60GB for Moodledata storage.

   Knowing this, in order to use the Load Balancer, do I need to replicate the Moodle in another instance?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can place a load balancer in front of a single instance if you want, but it won't be "balancing" any load at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you need to answer for yourself is:

*"Can my Application be run on multiple servers?"*

Another term frequently used for this concept is:  "Application Clustering".

It so happens that Moodle does support a "Server Cluster" and they have documentation for that:  https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Server_cluster

What is clear is that both the database and storage needs to be shared for load balancing to work.  Databases are intrinsically capable of being clustered, so that is not an issue.

However, storing data on an ebs volume mounted on a server is not going to work.

You need some form of "shared" storage, which probably means an NFS server that all the "application instances" need to mount.  If you are not an experienced sysadmin/devops person this is likely to be quite an exercise.  You might also be able to use Amazon's [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) which is SaaS NFS essentially.

Once you know that your application can be clustered, then the question of using a load balancer comes into play.

With a Load balancer you certainly don't need 2 servers, but that is not the only reason you might use an aws "load balancer" aka "elastic load balancer".

With AWS you can (and in my opinion, should) put your servers inside a VPC.  That is good security practice, but again a non-trivial exercise.

With a VPC, a standard practice is to use an elastic load balancer to provide secured ingress to the application server(s).  Of course there is a significant cost to using AWS load balancers you should be aware of.

With any load balancer, you need to be aware of whether or not you need the LB to provide "sticky sessions."  A sticky session is provided by the load balancer, where it adds a cookie or url parameter that routes a user continuously to the same server in the LB once they have first been routed.  If you can avoid having to use sticky sessions that is best.

Without sticky sessions, the LB can round robin requests to the cluster.

This goes to the idea of session management, and whether session state for the application lives on a server or across the cluster.

Again Moodle has options for this.  If you store session data in the database it should work without sticky sessions in a clustered setup (with a LB in front) once you have multiple servers, however if you are using memcached for session storage (which is recommended for performance) then the memcacheD instance needs to be shared, just as the database and file storage need to be shared.  That means you will be running memcached either as an amazon service, or on it's own server (or memcached cluster) or even on the same server you are running as the NFS server.

If you wanted to have a small memcacheD per Moodle server, then you would need sticky sessions turned on in your LB.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are very vague, as it is not clear what kind of load you want to balance. Eg. there are for example cpu-bound or i/o bound appications which could create a high-load on your site. You could use load balancing in order to distribute the work to several instances. So in short:

1. Yes, you should go for two or more instances.
2. I'd say probably yes.

One common example would be a webserver hosting a website. When users of your website increase, more requests would come in to fetch the content. (But there are problably tons of different ways to distribute load on this kind of application, eg. caches, use of a cdn, etc)

Probably see [elb getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html) from amazon.